# Magento: jQuery plugin installation

Tags: jquery, magento

I just installed the [Magento jQuery library and plugins](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mygento-jquery-library-and-powerful-plugins.html) plugin, but using the `$` operator still returns *Prototype*. Looking at the FAQ of the plugin, they say:

> Check that your template is using head reference and check your layouts folder for our xml

I'm a newbie, so I don't know what this exactly means. Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jQuery` instead of  `$`, as it is needed to avoid conflicts between Prototype and jQuery.

Comment: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: Have you cleaned your cache ? Which package do you use for your design ? (look at the path of a front-end CSS file, eg in `skin/frontend/example_package/default/styles.css` the package is `example_package`)

Comment: did clean cache. I have my own design package. should I declare something somewhere?

Comment: Try to copy the `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/mygento` directory to `app/design/frontend/[your_package]/default/layout`, so that it can be taken into account (and still use `jQuery` instead of `$`)

Comment: did it. and flushed cache. nothing

Comment: jquery is not appearing inside any script tag

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.noConflict().
It will help to solve.http://goo.gl/NF9Xs

Comment: the problem is that the jquery javascript is not included in my document

Comment: add like the following way in your layout
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
         <reference name="head">
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/samdoit/jscal2.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>samdoit/jscal2.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>samdoit/en.js</script></action>
        </reference>
</default>
</layout>